# Show one or more elements and their content that have been hidden

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck and not sure how to move on. I want to be able to click a tab to reveal its content. With the code I currently have, when I click a single tab, it reveals the content for all the tabs. But I just want the click to reveal the content that's associated with that single tab. I'm looking for a vanilla javascript solution.

Here's the code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KCJAc (inline below)

CSS:

```
.tab-content {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.tab-active {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var tabHeaders = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-header');
for (var i = 0; i < tabHeaders.length; i++) {
    tabHeaders[i].addEventListener('click', activateTab);
}

function activateTab() {
    var tabContents = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-content');
    for (var i = 0; i < tabContents.length; i++) {
        tabContents[i].classList.add('tab-active');
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <h3 class="tab-header">Tab1</h3>
  <p class="tab-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium odio iste aliquam molestias corporis blanditiis nihil soluta sint illum quibusdam reprehenderit sed quaerat iusto maiores error iure ducimus dicta ipsum.</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h3 class="tab-header">Tab2</h3>
  <p class="tab-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium odio iste aliquam molestias corporis blanditiis nihil soluta sint illum quibusdam reprehenderit sed quaerat iusto maiores error iure ducimus dicta ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I see. I'll take note of this in the future. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: I've moved it into the question for you this time, as you're new! (And retracted my close vote.) You may feel you've gotten conflicting requests, as someone asked you to use jsbin on another question. Putting the code in the question is necessary. *Also* doing a http://jsbin.com / http://jsfiddle.net / http://codepen.io and linking to it is a nice-to-have, but not a requirement. In both cases, always post the [minimum necessary to replicate the problem](http://sscce.org). (You've done that here.) Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding `tab-active` to **all** of the `tab-content` elements. You just want to add it to the one following the header that's clicked: [Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/izrkJ)

```
var tabHeaders = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-header');
for (var i = 0; i < tabHeaders.length; i++) {
    tabHeaders[i].addEventListener('click', activateTab);
}

function activateTab() {
    var tabContents = this.nextElementSibling;
    while (tabContents && (!tabContents.classList || !tabContents.classList.contains("tab-content"))) {
        tabContents = tabContents.nextElementSibling;
    }
    if (tabContents) {
        tabContents.classList.toggle("tab-active");
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I'm using `nextElementSibling` to get the next sibling that's an element since you used `classList` in the original, so I figure you're only using this code on fairly up-to-date browsers. If you intend to use it on older browsers, you can use `nextSibling` instead (and also use `className` rather than `classList`.

Comment: Whoa this solution is perfect as far as I'm concerned. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because by using `document.getElementsByClassName` you are getting all `tab-content` tabs in your *page*, rather than the *DOM level* of the clicked `tab-header` element. You can use the [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling) property of `tab-header` to get the next DOM node beside `tab-header`:

```
function activateTab() {
    this.nextSibling.classList.add("tab-active");
}
```

Or, if you are not sure if `tab-content` will definitely appear directly after `tab-header` you can query [parentNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector):

```
function activateTab() {
    this.parentNode.querySelector(".tab-content").classList.add("tab-active");
}
```

Note this last method won't work in anything lower than IE8, but then again neither will the `classList` property in your original question.